# Memory leak when streaming HLS on hosted webapp UWP on xbox

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, hosted, xbox-one

The basic example [provided in github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TVHelpers/blob/master/tvjs/examples/MediaPlayer/Basic/BasicMediaPlayer.html) can not play a `.m3u8` with a duration > 40 minutes. Memory grows pretty fast and does not seem to be disposed properly:

[image]

After 10-20 minutes of playback, the app usually crashes. I tried with both `<video>` element and the TVJS MediaPlayer helper, observing similar behavior.

It is noteworthy to say that this does not happen when streaming the same page with Edge, but I guess that app has better privileges/memory management than the webview used for hosted webapps.

There are probably a bunch of hosted webapps in the xbox store that do not have memory problems, am I missing something?

Comment: I have test you providing sample. But I could not load .m3u8 file by webview httpcontent. Could show me how to do that?

Comment: @Nico [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/vgrafe/d4abc450d94d3757e897de068c023b1d)

Comment: I tried to use this [link](https://albaniaiptv.com/iptv/uk.m3u) as  `<video>` source. And other code  is the same as yours. But the player noticed me  `Playback was interrupted. Please try again`.

Comment: Your link seems corrupted, no player will read it (you can try [here])(https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/). the [BBB video](http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:bigbuckbunnyiphone.smil/chunklist-b400000.m3u8) works. I would share the feature length streams I have, but they are under copyright and accessible to our subscribers only, so you'll have to provide your own m3u8 to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone landing here - a recent update fixed the leak. This was confirmed with talks to a customer service member.